# Check if a function can take a certain argument, positional or keyword, in Python

Tags: python

```py
from inspect import signature, Parameter


def check_can_take_positional_arg(fun, arg_ix):
    params = signature(fun).parameters.values()
    return len(params) >= arg_ix + 1 or any(
        param.kind == Parameter.VAR_POSITIONAL for param in params
    )


def check_can_take_keyword_arg(fun, arg_key):
    params = signature(fun).parameters.values()
    return any(
        param.kind == Parameter.VAR_KEYWORD
        or (
            param.kind in [Parameter.KEYWORD_ONLY, Parameter.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD]
            and param.name == arg_key
        )
        for param in params
    )
```

Can something be improved about this code?

Comment: What situation is this being applied to?

Comment: I’m writing a function that takes a function and a key, an `int` or a `str`, and produces a new function where the parameter specified by the key is curried out. It uses this logic to check that the specified key can be taken by the function to error early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that would hugely improve it is a comprehensive test suite. Maybe you have that and just haven't shown it, but if not this is exactly the sort of fiddly code which rewards systematic automated testing.

In particular in writing such tests, you'd want to check

- `def foo():` Functions with no parameters
- `def foo(a, b, /):` Functions with positional only arguments
- `def foo(a, *, b):` Functions with keyword only arguments and no *args.
- `def foo(self, a, b):` Methods
- Combinations of the above.

I think that third case (keyword only) may fail at the moment, in the direction of falsely promising to accept a positional parameter for b.

Based on your comment about the purpose, it may also be necessary to test the interaction of multiple calls. For example, What happens if you try to curry out parameter 1 and 2, but after the first step there aren't two positions left open? What happens if the same parameter is picked out by position and by keyword? How does that change if there is also a **kwargs parameter ready to grab any excess?

Beyond prodding at edge cases, I'd have a few minor thoughts which are very much stylistic.

- It feels odd to see `>=` paired with a `+ 1`, instead of just using `>`.
- What happens if someone gives a negative `arg_ix` value?
- Parameter.VAR_POSITIONAL and friends are enums. Although the examples in the docs don't bother with this, there are some advantages to using `is` rather than `==` for comparing Enums and the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/enum.html?highlight=enum#comparisons) say that "Enum members are compared by identity".
- For code devoted to checking whether parameters are legal, it may be worthwhile (or at least poetically appropriate!) to add type annotations.

Overall, this seems like quite clean code taken in a sensible sort of direction.